# running cpp project with cmake (mac)

Tags: compilation, cmake

My question is very naive. Every time I ran an algorithm, it's with an IDE so I don't know exactly what is generated in backgrown.
I try to run with my MacBook an algorithm that I didn't write and I'm blocked !

In the readme file: they said "Use cmake to generate desired projects on different platforms. (See “CM.txt” in the
“src” folder)"

In the CM.txt:

```
project(BlProj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
add_executable(BlProj
   main.cpp
   thi.cpp
   thu.cpp
   mat.cpp
   Config.cpp
   Stringer.cpp
   )
```

I did: cmake CM.txt
A CM directory is generated. I will not list all the files inside: it's some cmake, bin, out, cpp, c, cxx, log, txt files.
I don't know what I can do with that!
I'm supposed to generate a compiled binary and run it with the command:

```
./BlProj data1 data2 10 config output
```

But it wasn't generated...

So I don't know how I can have the BlProj executable. Could you help me?
How do the cpp compilation work? What did cmake exactly? 
Is cmake CM.txt is a good practice or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cmake-gui to build sources.

go to CMAKE installation directory and inside bin folder run `cmake-gui`

Provide input where the source code is and provide an input where to build.
hit on configure and then generate.

you might need to select IDE version as well as provide additional input, it depends.

once done open generated project files with your IDE and build.

Comment: I don't have cmake-gui on my mac. I tried brew install cmake-gui but I have an error
Error: No available formula with the name "cmake-gui" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.